# How to configure WEBrick error handling?

Tags: ruby, webrick

```
@server = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new( config )    

@server.mount_proc '/' do | req, res |
  ...
end

fork do
  @server.start
end
```

The default error handling returns the error in the body of a 500 response.

What is a good way to log exceptions instead of returning them in the body of the response?